# Show that $\frac 1x \ge 3 - 2\sqrt{x}$ for all positive real numbers $x$. Describe when we have equality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $\frac 1x \ge 3 - 2\sqrt{x}$ for all positive real numbers $x$. Describe when we have equality.

I'm kinda stuck on how to do this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try expanding $\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)^2(2\sqrt{x}+1)}{x}$.

Answer (score 4):

By AM-GM, we have
$$
\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{x}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}\frac{1}{x}}=3.
$$
Equality is iff $\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{x}$ iff $x=1$.

Comment: Quite literally the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that $x>0$ we may multiply both sides of

\begin{equation}
\frac 1x \ge 3 - 2\sqrt{x}
\end{equation}

by $x$ to obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
1 &\ge& 3x - 2x\sqrt{x}\\
2x\sqrt{x}-3x+1&\ge&0
\end{eqnarray}

Substitute $u=\sqrt{x}$ and rewrite the inequality as

\begin{equation}
2u^3-3u^2+1\ge0
\end{equation}

Next, notice that $u=1$ is a solution and use this to factor the left side as

\begin{eqnarray}
(u-1)(2u^2-u-1)&\ge&0\\
(u-1)(2u+1)(u-1)&\ge&0\\
(u-1)^2(2u+1)&\ge&0
\end{eqnarray}

The first factor is never negative and the second factor is non-negative for all $u\ge-\frac{1}{2}$. But for $x\ge0$ it is true that $u\ge0$, so the original inequality holds for all $x\ge0$.

Answer (score -1):

We want to prove:

$(1)$ $$\forall x>0, \frac{1}{x} \geq 3-2\sqrt{x}  $$

Let's consider two cases:

Case $1$: $3-2\sqrt{x} \geq 0 \Rightarrow x \leq \frac{9}{4}$

Then both sides of the inequality are positive.

$\frac{1}{x} \geq 3 - 2\sqrt{x} \Leftrightarrow  3x - 2x^{1.5}\leq 1 \Leftrightarrow x> 0$

Therefore the inequality $(1)$ holds for $0< x\leq \frac{9}{4}$

Case $2$: $x>\frac{9}{4}$

Then we clearly see that $3-2\sqrt{x} < 0 $ and $\frac{1}{x} > 0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x} > 3-2\sqrt{x}$

So generalising to all $x>0$, we get that

$\frac{1}{x} \geq 3-2\sqrt{x}$ as required.